# How to send Logon messages in sequential order?

Tags: quickfix, quickfixn

The QuickFix/n send `Logon` messages automatically in parallel and looks like I can't control that. I have read all poor docs related to this library and doesn't found how to send `Logon` messages one by one.

I want to send `Logon` messages in sequential order i.e. send first `Logon` message and receive `Logon` response, then send second `Logon` message and receive second `Logon` response and so on.

Is it possible to do with QuickFix/n?

P.S. I want such strange things because looks like third-party FIX server required that I send `Logon` messages sequentially.

**Problem Solved**

The support team of third-party FIX server sent a message where they said that `Logon` messages should be send **simultaneously**. So, my decision (about sequential `Logon` messages) was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your initiator or acceptor will not attempt logon until you call `.Start()`.

So I suppose you'll need to set up some logic so that you don't call `Start()` on your second initiator until your first is connected (which you can detect via the first initiator's Application class callbacks).

I'm really curious who your counterparty is.  Between this and your other questions, they seem to have done things in a very unorthodox way.